# Moving text in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

In every text editor you are able to select an area of text and then move it to another location by clicking the selected text with the left mouse button and dragging it to the desired location.
But when I try to do that in Xamarin Studio and it returns back to the original location and nothing happens.
What should I do? Is there a way out of this?

Comment: @choper I am not talking about the **UI designer**, but about the **code editor** and the **code editor** is a **text editor**. In every code editor (like Visual Studio, eclipse, NetBeans etc.) you are able to move lines of code by selecting it and moving it with the mouse to a new position. But I am not able to do that in the code editor of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Why not Cut and Paste?

Comment: @Jason, of course it is possible to use cut and paste. It is just a matter usability, speed and performance. Every editor is offering this feature. Isn't there this feature in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Same problem here and I'm using v5.0. From this thread there seems to be no workaround yet: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16359

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alt+Up or Alt+Down to move the current line (or selection) up or down (respectively).

You can also select text and then drag & drop it somewhere else in the editor.

If this isn't working for you, what platform are you on and what version are you using? (I'm using 4.2.4 on Mac and it works - I just tried it)

Comment: Alt+Up and Alt+Down works fine, but the drag & drop (and that is what I am looking for) doesn't work.  
I am using Xamarin 4.2.3 on Windows and the website of Xamarin says that this the latest version (March 6, 2014).

Comment: It's possible there is a bug on the Windows platform. Could you submit a bug report to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com?